# Create array through function

Tags: php

Is there any way to return an array, something like:

```
$array = [
    "parcela" => "1",
    "valor"   => "100",
];
```

Using the function below? I need to return an array with the number of plots and the value:

Function PHP

```
function calcParcelaJuros($valor_total,$parcelas,$juros=0) {
    if($juros==0) {
         $string = 'PARCELA - VALOR <br />';
         for($i=1;$i<($parcelas+1);$i++) {
            $string .= $i.'x (Sem Juros) - R$.number_format($valor_total/$parcelas, 2, ",", ".").' <br />';
         }
         return $string;
     } else {
         $string = 'PARCELA - VALOR <br />';
         for($i=1;$i<($parcelas+1);$i++) {
            $I =$juros/100.00;
            $valor_parcela = $valor_total*$I*pow((1+$I),$parcelas)/(pow((1+$I),$parcelas)-1);
            $string .= $i.'x (Juros de: '.$juros.'%) - R$ '.number_format($valor_parcela, 2, ",", ".").' <br />';
         }
         return $string;
     }
}
print(calcParcelaJuros(250,4,2));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only have to save the data on the array, properly formatted as you need, the use the `return` statement and you are good to go.

You can see, that php's return statement can `return` values even by reference, as it is explained [here](http://php.net/manual/es/functions.returning-values.php); check the second example, it will help you.

---

But for the sake of giving you a fast example, you can do whatever you need inside the function:

```
function calcParcelaJuros($valor_total,$parcelas,$juros=0) {
  $parcelas = array();

  if($juros==0) {
    for($i=1;$i<($parcelas+1);$i++) {
      ...
      ...
      $parcelas[] = ["parcela" => "1", "valor"   => "100"]
    }

    return $parcelas;
  } else {    
    ...
    ...
  }
}
```

You can make any process you require, save the info in the array, then return it.